# Lumen/Laravel Query Builder 2D Array

Tags: arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5, lumen

Been going at this for a few hours and cant seem to get it right.

Basically I have the below `sql` I'm moving over to `Lumen` for my `API`

```
$data = array();
$query = "SELECT dept.name AS dept_name, r.id AS id, r.name AS role_name FROM careers_dept AS dept INNER JOIN careers_roles AS r ON dept.id = r.dept_id";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // read into 2D array
        $row['seoName'] = seoUrl($row['role_name']);
        $data[$row['dept_name']][] = $row;
    }
    $response = json_encode($data);
}
return $response;
```

This is what I have so far;

```
$roles = DB::connection('careers')->table('careers_dept')
    ->join('careers_roles', 'careers_roles.dept_id', '=', 'careers_dept.id')
    ->select('careers_roles.id', 'careers_roles.name', 'careers_dept.name')
    ->get();

foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $role->seo = $this->seoUrl($role->name);
}

$data['data'] = $roles;
$data['success'] = true;

$response = json_encode($data);
return $response;
```

For starters, i can't figure out how to access the elements of the array correctly like in this line

```
$row['seoName'] = seoUrl($row['role_name']);
```

Both tables have `name` as a column but with normal `sql` you can use `AS` to give an alias which is how I did with normal `sql`.

And then this line is also something I can't work out how to convert it. The below line creates the `2D array` making `dept_name` a parent array.

```
$data[$row['dept_name']][] = $row;
```

I also loop through the array to get an attribute, transform it using a private function and then inject it back in

```
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $role->seo = $this->seoUrl($role->name);
}
```

This does work but I'm grabbing the wrong `name` attribute because both tables have a column with the same name.

Comment: WHATEVER YOU DO, 
DON'T EVER USE LUMEN!  
https://github.com/kenjis/php-framework-benchmark/issues/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AS` in Laravel query builder as well:

```
 ->select(
      'careers_roles.id', 
      'careers_roles.name as role_name', 
      'careers_dept.name as dept_name'
 )
```

And you can group results by dept_name with `groupBy` method of `Collection` class (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-groupby).

So your final code could look like that:

```php
$roles = DB::connection('careers')
    ->table('careers_dept')
    ->join('careers_roles', 'careers_roles.dept_id', '=', 'careers_dept.id')
    ->select(
         'careers_roles.id', 
         'careers_roles.name as role_name', 
         'careers_dept.name as dept_name'
    )
    ->get();

foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $role->seo = $this->seoUrl($role->role_name);
}

//convert into collection, group by "dept_name" key and then convert back into array
$data = collect($roles)->groupBy('dept_name')->all();
```